# Python KeyError JSON

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get some specific data from a JSON file, but I get the following error:

```
for item in data['perfil'][0]['regimes']: KeyError: 'regimes'
```

This is my script, as you can see, I am trying to get Key `regimes`, because it has specific data, that others don't have:

```
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('backupperfil.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for item in data['perfil'][0]['regimes']:
    print(item['classificacao'])
```

And this is a small copy of Json File:

```
{
"perfil":[
    {
        "data": 1533815887,
        "kmh": 0,
        "rpm": 0.0,
        "pedal": 15.294117647058824
    },
    {
        "data": 1533815888,
        "kmh": 0
        ,"rpm": 0.0
        ,"pedal": 15.294117647058824
    },
    {
        "data": 1533815889,
        "kmh": 0
        ,"rpm": 0.0
        ,"pedal": 15.294117647058824
    },
    {
        "kmh": 0
        ,"rpm": 834.75
        ,"pedal": 14.117647058823529
    },
    {
        "regimes": [
            {
                "kmh": 0,
                "rpm": 833.75,
                "pedal": 14.117647058823529,
                "regime_inferior_normal": 318,
                "regime_normal": 27,
                "regime_agressivo": 1,
                "regime_muito_agressivo": 0,
                "soma_regimes": 346,
                "classificacao": "Regime Inferior a Normal"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "kmh": 0,
        "rpm": 827.5,
        "pedal": 14.117647058823529
    }
]
}
```

How can I get the data inside of Key "regimes"?

Comment: `data['perfil'][4]['regimes']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if you have more than regimes in your json. I'm assuming so , since you gave only a part of your original json

```
for i in js['perfil']:
    if 'regimes' in i:
        print(i['regimes'][0]['classificacao'])
```

This way the the program loops through each jsonobject and checks for the key `regimes` . If it exists, then it'll be printed

Comment: The call to `keys` is superfluous; a `dict` iterator yields the keys of the `dict`.

Comment: Thank you, it fixed my problem o/////

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code:-

```
data['perfil'][4]['regimes'][0]['classificacao']
```

Make sure the indexes you are using are right.